# How electronjs pops up the context menu of a file in windows

Tags: c++, windows, electron

I am implementing one. After clicking a button in the electron window with the mouse, the context menu (right-click system menu) of a file will pop up.
I use node-addon-api
c++:

```
Napi::Boolean ContextMenu(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
    // CoInitialize
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    // 获取文件路径
    std::string filePath = info[1].ToString().Utf8Value();
    // 获取文件的 IShellItem 接口
    IShellItem* pItem;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(StringToLPCWSTR(UTF8ToGBK(filePath.c_str())), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create shell item." << std::endl;
        return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), false);
    }
    // 获取文件的 IContextMenu 接口
    IContextMenu* pContextMenu;
    hr = pItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pContextMenu));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get context menu." << std::endl;
        pItem->Release();
        return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), false);
    }
    // 创建菜单
    HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    if (hMenu == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create menu." << std::endl;
        pContextMenu->Release();
        pItem->Release();
        return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), false);
    }
    hr = pContextMenu->QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, 0x7FFF, CMF_NORMAL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to query context menu." << std::endl;
        DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        pContextMenu->Release();
        pItem->Release();
        return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), false);
    }
    // 显示菜单
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    // 获取当前窗口句柄
    Napi::Buffer<void *> buffer = info[0].As<Napi::Buffer<void *>>();
    HWND hWnd = static_cast<HWND>(*reinterpret_cast<void **>(buffer.Data()));
    if (!IsWindow(hWnd)) {
        std::cout << "Invalid window handle" << std::endl;
        return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), false);
    }
    int command = TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD, pt.x, pt.y, hWnd, NULL);
    if (command == 0)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to display menu. Error code: " << err << std::endl;
    }
    // 释放资源
    DestroyMenu(hMenu);
    pContextMenu->Release();
    pItem->Release();
    // CoUninitialize
    CoUninitialize();
    return Napi::Boolean::New(info.Env(), true);
}
```

nodejs:

```
global.api.ContextMenu(global.mainWindow.getNativeWindowHandle(), index.getAbsolutePath(item.path))
```

After calling the ContextMenu method, the code TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD, pt.x, pt.y, hWnd, NULL) always returns 0. Why? and no context menu pops up.

GetLastError always returns 0

The context menu can pop up normally

Comment: I actually tried GetLastError, but that also returns 0 every time.

Comment: It has been revised. Thank you.